# Exportar html para PDF com html2pdf background-size nao funciona

Tags: php, html, css

Boas,
Estou tentando converter uma pagina html para pdf utilizando html2pdf, mas ao que parece o background-size:cover nao esta funcionando.

Na minha pagina web a minha imagem fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao converter para PDF a imagem perde as formaçoes css e fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código e o seguinte `<div class="imagem" style="background-image: url(ficheiros/foto.png); background-position: center; background-size:cover; backgroud-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>`

Alguem sabe alguma forma de eu conseguir que a imagem no pdf preencha a div na totalidade sem repetição?

Comment: dua div utiliza uma classe imagem, mostra pra mim o que tem nessa classe

Comment: Poste o link da lib que vc está usando, qual é esse html2pdf que vc usa, tem o link do projeto dele?

Comment: No exemplo que postou o `background` está escrito de forma incorreta - `backgroud-repeat: no-repeat;`. O seu código está assim também?

Comment: .imagem{border: 7px solid #e0e0e0; border-top-left-radius: 50px; border-bottom-right-radius: 50px; height:340px; width:265px; overflow:hidden;}

Answer (score 2):

**Edição em 4/7/19.** A implementação https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf, de fato, praticamente ignora a propriedade `background-size`, e esse não é o primeiro problema deles com [CSS](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=css). Você pode contribuir no projeto, melhorando-o ou apenas informando o problema, ou pode apenas ajustar as dimensões da imagem manualmente de modo que fique satisfatória no PDF. Ou, além disso, pode seguir a sugestão abaixo.

Existem várias implementações de *html2pdf*. Eu sugiro a você o [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html). Ele é bastante poderoso para reproduzir HTML's não triviais em PDF, por usar o motor do Qt WebKit.

Por exemplo, você não expos o que tem na sua classe CSS imagem (`class="imagem"`), mas para preencher uma `<div>` com uma imagem, com as dimensões, seria algo mais ou menos assim (testado no Chrome, Firefox e Safari):

```css
#com_imagem_de_fundo {
  height: 256px;
  width: 512px;
  
  background-image: url(https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/0288/production/_105284600_44935b21-9f20-4727-a2c0-84bef85a4548.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="com_imagem_de_fundo"></div>
```

Assumindo que os trechos acima estão dispostos adequadamente num arquivo *pagina.html*, gere o *pagina.pdf* pela linha de comando:

```bsh
$ wkhtmltopdf pagina.html pagina.pdf
```

Ou, no PHP, usando o [phpwkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf):

```php
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;

$pdf = new Pdf('pagina.html');
if (!$pdf->saveAs('pagina.pdf')) {
  $erro = $pdf->getError();
  // ... lide com o erro
}
?>
```

Rode `composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf` no diretório de *pagina.html*, para testar. Observo que o comando `wkhtmltopdf` deve estar já funcionando no sistema (*phpwkhtmltopdf* é um pequeno *wrapper*).

Comment: Mas o `wkhtmltopdf` não tenho que instalar algo no servidor? As vezes não temos acesso ao servidor por isto ele é um pouco mais complicado utilizar.

Comment: Sim, ele deve ser instalado no sistema. Apesar disso, é uma boa alternativa. ;)

Comment: @TiedtTech, veja https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf , como outra alternativa. Mas já observo que este está em conformidade com [CSS 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/colors.html#q14.0), no qual ainda não está definida a propriedade *background-size*; além disso, no *dompdf* a propriedade *float* está em desenvolvimento